# Metal Oxide Varistor connection

Tags: surge-protection, over-voltage-protection, mov

How do I select the MOV for a multiple operating voltages. Consider the diagram below, when switch is in position 2-1 and 5-4 (both primary winding are connected in series), I can apply an input voltage up to 230V and when switch is in position 2-3 and 5-6 (both primary winding are connected in parallel) then I can apply up to 115V at the input. How can I select the MOV voltage rating and how do I connect the MOV in this circuit? Can I just connect MOV with working voltage of 115V parallel to each primary winding?
[image: MOV]

Comment: You'll also need a fuse.

Comment: Obviously. I just missed to include it in the image. Sorry.

Comment: What is the worst case AC voltage you might apply on both switch positions? How do you avoid having the incorrect switch position and blowing the transformer? What actually are you trying to protect? What are you trying to protect against?

Comment: I wish to prevent high voltage being applied on input side such as from surges. Usually MOVs are found at the input side in the SMPS right? I wish to implement a circuit similar to that.

Comment: To protect what?

Comment: ICs from over voltages on the secondary side.

Comment: That is normally done on the rectified and smoothed DC side by using a voltage regulator.

Comment: Voltage regulators have maximum input voltage rating. Over voltage on primary of transformer causes higher voltage on secondary, much higher than the maximum input voltage rating of the regulator, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How do I select the MOV for a multiple operating voltages.*

What actually are you trying to protect? What are you trying to protect against?

> *I wish to prevent high voltage being applied on input side such as
> from surges.*

To protect what?

> *ICs from over voltages on the secondary side*

Then use a voltage regulator on the secondary side. This will protect your circuits if designed correctly and, you probably need one anyway irrespective of surges.

> *Voltage regulators have maximum input voltage rating. Over voltage on
> primary of transformer causes higher voltage on secondary, much higher
> than the maximum input voltage rating of the regulator, right?*

Voltage regulator circuits can be designed to easily operate over a 4:1 DC voltage range AND cope with spikes due to surges. But you have to begin by "understanding the enemy" and that enemy is usually indirect lightning surges because they can be long-enough to force a small surge into the secondary circuit.

The transformer can actually help deal with surges because surges are usually earth referenced and the transformer is really good at dealing with the rejection of common-mode surges occurring on the primary.

And, in addition to all that, when dealing with the low voltage DC side of a circuit, TVS diodes can be more effective and longer-lived than MOV devices because MOVs can only protect against a limited number of surges before they (tend) to go short circuit. A TVS is more reliable and they can be chosen with greater accuracy.